# Iterating Generators in a For Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, xml-parsing, nested, generator

I'm trying to parse XML from the [National Weather Service](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=36.06000&lon=-94.16000&FcstType=digitalDWML); printing the hourly temperature, a blank space, and the associated time of that hourly temperature.

Printing the temperatures simply requires a for loop.  The problem is indexing the correct time-stamp while looping and printing each temperature.  Example children in /data/time-layout look like this:

```
<layout-key>k-p1h-n1-0</layout-key>
<start-valid-time>2014-06-30T13:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2014-06-30T14:00:00-05:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2014-06-30T14:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2014-06-30T15:00:00-05:00</end-valid-time>
```

The desired snippets are all and only "start-valid-time" nodes.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2  

url = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=36.06000&lon=-94.16000&FcstType=digitalDWML"
tree = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
forecast = tree.getroot()
i = int(0)

Temperatures = forecast.find("./data/parameters/temperature[@type='hourly']")

for HourTemperature in Temperatures:
    TimeStamps = forecast.findall("./data/time-layout/start-valid-time") #Reference 1
    print HourTemperature.text, "  ", TimeStamps[i].text #Reference 2
    i += 1
```

Running "python [program name].py" yields

```
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Which makes sense when the above lines Reference 1 and 2 are wrong.  I believe my problem is caused by a misunderstanding of generators.

Thank ya'll in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your `import` statement is correct? `import elementtree.ElementTree as ET` - should be `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` as far as I understand. The code works fine for me, no errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, alexce.  What output are you getting?

Comment: Multiple lines from `88    2014-06-30T14:00:00-05:00` to `85    2014-07-07T13:00:00-05:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine here with a slight import modification that may have to do with me running python 2.7.4 on Ubuntu.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

The rest works as is.

Comment: Well, alexce and Mike Mattice, thanks for debugging?  I thought I had a more substantial problem worthy of your time.